# ajax POST int parameter in asp.net core

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I am migrating my MVC project to Core and I have been having a hard time fixing all the old ajax calls.

I can pass a model and string parameters into the controller, however, ints are not working for me.

I can wrap them into a JSON object as a string parameter such as `[FromBody]string objId` in the controller, but then I have to parse the int val from the Json `{'objId' : 1}`.

Is there a way I can avoid this and just pass an int?

below is the code I am trying.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult PassIntFromView([FromBody]int objId)
{
    //DO stuff with int here
}
```

here is the js.

```
var data = { "objId": 1};
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("PassIntFromView", "ControllerName")',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(data) {
            //do stuff with json result 
        },
        error: function(passParams) {
            console.log("Error is " + passParams);
        }
    });
```

The `objId` is always 0 in the controller.

I have tried this without doing `JSON.stringify(data)` as well with no result.

I have also tried all the different form attribute variations.

Comment: This works for me:   var data = 1;   public IActionResult PassIntFromView([FromBody] int caseId). You're passing just the number, and you can ONLY pass one variable as a parameter; int, string, boolean etc. The minute you add more paramters, it has to be wrapped in a model at the Controller end.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try to use contentType as `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`:

```
 var data = { objId: 1 };
 $.ajax({
     url: '@Url.Action("PassIntFromView", "ControllerName")',
     type: "post",
     contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
     data: data,
     success: function (result) {
         console.log(result);
     }
 });
```

Then remove the `[FromBody]` attribute in the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult PassIntFromView(int objId)
{
    //Do stuff with int here
}
```

Comment: Why it works with "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and not with "application/json"? Is it because of some configuration ?

Comment: does anyone knows the answer of @chunk1ty 's question ?

Comment: I think it is in the start up. Mine is configured to
`services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(o =>
{
    o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
    o.JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = null;
});`
under the `void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method

Answer (score 5):

I believe your issue could be that you are passing an object to the api, but trying to turn it into a primitive. I know there is already a chosen answer, but give this a whirl.

```
var data = { };
data["objId"] = 1; //I just wanted to show you how you can add values to a json object
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("PassIntFromView", "ControllerName")',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data) {
        //do stuff with json result 
    },
    error: function(passParams) {
        console.log("Error is " + passParams);
    }
});
```

You create a model class

```
public class MyModel {
     public int ObjId {get;set;}
}
```

Your controller should expect one of these

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult PassIntFromView([FromBody] MyModel data)
{
    //DO stuff with int here
}
```

Comment: Yes this works for me, but I wanted to do it without having to wrap a primitive in a model. But if someone wants to pass a model this is a great example!

Comment: Copy that. I was on an upvote spree, and found this question. Figured I would give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

JSON has a preference for strings not integers. You are better off to use JSON.stringify(data) to parse to your controller, convert that to a integer in the controller, then parse the string that was returned as:

```
var data = { objId: 1};
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("PassIntFromView", "ControllerName")',//asp.net - url: 'api/controllerName/controllerFunction'
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data) {
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        //do stuff with json result 
    },
    error: function(passParams) {
        console.log("Error is " + passParams);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = { "objId": 1};
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("PassIntFromView", "ControllerName")',
    data: data,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data) {
        //do stuff with json result 
    },
    error: function(passParams) {
        console.log("Error is " + passParams);
    }
});
```

Your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult PassIntFromView(int objId)
{
    //DO stuff with int here
}
```

Comment: this will still pass back 0 for me.

Answer (score 0):

Js

```
var data = { "objId": 1};

$.ajax({

    url: "ControllerName/PassIntFromView",

    data: data,

    type: "POST",

    dataType: 'JSON',   

    success: function(data.result!=null) {

    console.log(data.result);

    },
    error: function(passParams) {
        console.log("Error is " + passParams);
    }

});
```

Comment: [HttpPost]

    public IActionResult  PassIntFromView (int objId)
    {
        
    }

Comment: with this I still get my objId as 0.

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer didn't work for me, what worked was to stringify the integer directly on js. So change only the `data: JSON.stringify(data),` to `data: JSON.stringify(1),` in your code.

Answer (score -1):

I got it working like this

```
let numberFour = JSON.stringify(4);

$.ajax({
    .......
    .......
    data: numberFour,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    contentType: "application/json",
    ......
    ........
});
```